# bidirectional bar chart (horizontal) with multiple measurement units

Tags: graph, charts, figure

I want to generate a bidirectional (=2 sided, mirror shape, similar to the pyramid chart)  bar chart (horizontal) with multiple measurement units. I would appreciate any insights. Thanks,

The graph I am trying to produce is similar to the following plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6ZfA.png)

Comment: You can visit the d3js website for getting the ideas and the thing you want, if it does not work, you can also make this from scratch with the aid of `HTML Canvas`.

Comment: tips on finding the solution for the problem